# ElasticSearch Gem - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I have big database, and i want use `Elasticsearch` for form search. In form search it have 15 table, each table has 50 record so if i want use `Elasticsearch` mapping , someone help me about it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use Searchkick, a wrapper gem for Elasticsearch: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

Comment: Thanks Leventhan, so I have see it but my databases many table. I have big database, and i want use Elasticsearch for form search. In form search it have 15 table, each table has 50 record so if i want use Elasticsearch mapping , someone help me about it.

Comment: Have you looked at the gem I've mentioned? There are detailed instructions you can follow.

Comment: yes, i see but it only 2 table and i do follow it so i can't . you can help me url